Installing Python on Node/Playwright docker image?
I have been using Playwrights node docker image, defined here: https://playwright.dev/docs/docker
This includes all the browser dependencies/etc.. for the node version of docker. This has worked fine however i'm going to be integrating the testrail CLI to help upload playwright report results to testrail.
Unfortunately this requires python which is not installed (from what I can tell) on the playwright default docker file.
What's my best/easiest course of action here? Obviously I am not going to switch all my test cases, would it make more sense to use a self-created docker file? Is there some way I can install python in the docker file in gitlab? (Which is the ci system we are using now).
I'm not super familiar with docker outside of the basics. But I imagine installing python after the fact makes more sense?
What is the best game plan here? Thanks!

Have you tried adding RUN apt-get install python3 to your dockerfile? I'm assuming you are deriving an image from the playwright one right?

You can add more software on an base docker image using Docker file.

It's a pure docker question.

@ventsyv Well this is using an image within a gitlab CI.yml file so I don't know if I can do that within the docker image on gitlab? This is a playwright image from the microsoft docker registry.

The gitlab pipeline is defined in the .gitlab-ci.yml file in the root of your repository. If you open that file in a text editor, you'll see the various jobs the pipeline runs.
It will look something like this:
<some_job_name>:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.45.1-jammy
    script:
        - <some command>

What that means is that the job will run on the image provided.
In the script section you can add a call to install python ( apt-get install python3 for example)
More info here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/
This will install python3 every time the job runs, so a better approach might be to build your own custom image. This way python will be installed once and available in the image thus speeding up your pipeline. The downside is it takes some setting up.
More info on running CI/CD in containers: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html
The general steps are as follows:

You can create your custom image by creating a custom Dockerfile:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.45.1-jammy
RUN apt-get install python3


You run docker build and create the image
You publish the image to a registry (https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/push/)
Then you modify the CI to use your custom image for the job. (see job example above)
Finally you tell gitlab how to access the registry that has the custom image (see  the "Access an image from a private container registry" section of the Gitlab document on using docker images). Obviously you don't need to do this step if you publish to image to dockerhub

I hope this helps.

I hate the idea of needing to keep up with a custom image would install python3 every time be "that" bad? I guess it's not great if I have to do it every run though.

It's workable but  I'm guessing it will add around 1-2 minutes each time the pipeline runs. I suggest you can try it to see if you can live with that.

Creating a custom image is not that bad. You have to invest some time up front but once you have it, there is very little maintenance.
